# How to Update Column from a Column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

There are probably better ways, but this worked for me:

```
 Update t1 
 set t1.ListKey = t2.ListKey
 From Jet.LookupListItemEntity_Default t1 
 join (Select ListKey, Id from Jet.LookupListEntity_default) as t2
 on t1.ListId = t2.id
```

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Update t1 
 set t1.ListKey = t2.ListKey
 From Jet.LookupListItemEntity_Default t1 
 join Jet.LookupListEntity_default t2 on t1.ListId = t2.id
```